# MongoDB aggregation for sum documents very slow after unwrap

Tags: performance, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a large collection with orders from a shop and want to get a summary of all orders where a specific item was purchased e.g. in the last 30 days. My problem is, that it's very slow with >60.000 documents in that collection.

The documents look like this in JSON:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5531165b5e608cec23004e31"), 
    "Type" : NumberInt(2), 
    "Products" : [
        {
            "ProductId" : ObjectId("54a94242aa76d3db6cd5b23f"), 
            "Sku" : "abcdef", 
            "Quantity" : NumberInt(2), 
            "UnitPrice" : NumberInt(37)
        }, 
        {
            "ProductId" : ObjectId("54a9426baa76d3db6cd5fbce"), 
            "Sku" : "lmnopq", 
            "Quantity" : NumberInt(2), 
            "UnitPrice" : NumberInt(42)
        }
    ], 
    "Order" : "1234", 
    "Revenue" : NumberInt(158), 
    "Date" : ISODate("2015-04-14T12:55:28.000+0000"), 
    "Tax" : 25.23, 
    "Shipping" : NumberInt(20)
}
```

The query I use:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
{ $unwind: "$Products" }
{ $match: Date: { $gte: new Date("2015-03-21T00:00:00.000Z"), $lte: new Date("2015-04-19T23:59:59.999Z") }, Type: 2, Products.ProductId: ObjectId("54a94242aa76d3db6cd5b23f") }
{ $group: { _id: Products.ProductId, Sum: { $sum: 1 } } }
])
```

Is this a problem of the way the data is stored in the collection or did I make a mistake inside the query?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Use `$match` before `$unwind` so that you reduce the number of documents.

Comment: Thx! That did it. I thought it might get a problem to do a match on an array, which wasn't unwinded at that moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things you can do to speed up/ optimize the aggregation operation:

1) ensure that you have an index on the `Date` field,

2) place the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) as early in the aggregation pipeline as possible. Because **`$match`** operations minimize the amount of processing down the pipe.

Comment: Thx! There is already an index on the `Date` field. I put the `$match` before the `$unwind` now and it's faster now. Thought it might get a problem to do a match on an array before it's unwinded.